# Removing millisecond from datetime throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code in SQL Server 2016

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(8), ExpiryDate))
```

I get this result:

```
ExpiryDate
------------------------
2020-08-03 00:00:00.000
```

How can I remove the `.000` (the milliseconds part)?

Expected result should be:

```
2020-08-03 00:00:00
```

Please help

Comment: Why do you want to show HH:MI:SS if it's a DATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not using a `datetime`, which is accurate to 1/300th of a second. Instead define your value as a `datetime2(0)`, which is accurate to 1 second (due to having a precision of 0 on milliseconds):

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),ExpiryDate)
FROM ...
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff dbfiddle *always* shows dates and time data types in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn`

Comment: It seemed strange that it didn't work.  I'll delete the comment.

Comment: To confirm, use an IDE, and the milliseconds are missing. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsWnY.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the internal format and the display format.  If you want the value formatted in a particular way, then format it explicitly:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), expirydate, 121)
```

You can add this into the table as a computed column:

```
alter table t add expirydate_display as (CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), expirydate, 121))
```